# In Linux (Ubuntu), how do I determine which specific file was not found when I see "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, I give these commands and obtain this output:

```
soujanya@LLN-Ubuntu:~/workspace/openEAR-0.1.0$ ls -l SMILExtract
-rwxr-xr-x 1 soujanya soujanya 3789876 Aug 20  2009 SMILExtract
soujanya@LLN-Ubuntu:~/workspace/openEAR-0.1.0$ whoami
soujanya
soujanya@LLN-Ubuntu:~/workspace/openEAR-0.1.0$ ./SMILExtract
bash: ./SMILExtract: No such file or directory
soujanya@LLN-Ubuntu:~/workspace/openEAR-0.1.0$
```

SMILExtract is an executable file (not shell script) and I do not have access to the source code of this file. Maybe it calls some `system()` or maybe not, no way for me to know.

I have heard that this error might be if the file is 32-bit and I run it on a 64-bit system, so `No such file or directory` refers to the loader and not this file. I think this is not the cause in my case, but anyway, my question is:

Is there a way to find out WHICH file is `No such file or directory`? Maybe a special variable in Bash or something like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on askubuntu.com

Comment: If you run it via strace (`strace ./SMILExtract`) you should get some extra information.

Comment: @AlexP: Great, this seems to answer the question!

Comment: Great! I've changed it into an answer so it's a bit more obvious. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run programs with `strace`, a tool that shows you which system calls are used by a program. It'll produce a lot of output, but you can see the files your program attempts to open. Run your program like this:

```
strace ./SMILExtract
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure about the 32/64 bit question you could 'file ./SMILExtract'

Comment: This is also a good answer, but I can only choose one. The other answer comprises a greater number of problematic cases, while this one detects only one case. I would recommend you to add this info as a comment to the chosen answer, or maybe edit the other answer to include this info.